# Regex para validação de float em python

Tags: python, regex

> r"[+-]?\d*.?\d+"

Esta regex esta aceitando numeros com mais de um ponto Ex: 12.23.43 e não era pra aceitar...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente esta:

```
r"^([+-]?\d+)(\.\d+)?$"
```

#### DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/Mq2buZ/4

Comment: Muito obrigado camarada, funcionou perfeitamente!